# onchange using in formulary - select . How to keep the information?

Tags: javascript, select, onchange

Im doing a formulary in php + javascript, using onchange event for my select. When i choose an option onchange makes the jump to my function, but the problem is i dont keep my form, is like its opening a new page just with the information of my function so i lost the form, which i want to keep.

here is the code:

```
< SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript' >
function test(){
    document.write("test");
}

</SCRIPT>
<?php
for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
{
    echo "<SELECT NAME='proba' onchange='test()' >";
    echo "<OPTION VALUE='$i'>.$i.</OPTION>";
}?>
```

Sorry if the title is kinda confused but i dont know how to explain.

Comment: That's because when your function is called, the `document.write` is overwriting the entire page.

Comment: Why your `SELECT` tag is inside the loop?

Comment: yeah but if i put php code inside the function it doesnt work: <SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
 function jugadores(){
  <?php
   echo "testing";
  ?>
 }

</SCRIPT>

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are overwriting the document contents. Try that:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
        document.getElementById("myTestField").value = "TEST";
    }

    </SCRIPT>

    <?php
    echo "<SELECT NAME='proba' onchange='test()'>";
    for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
    {

        echo "<OPTION VALUE='$i'>.$i.</OPTION>";

    }
    echo "</SELECT>";
    echo "<INPUT id='myTestField'>";

?>
```

If you write on the document, the former element will get lost, this one should work.